Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W maximum SD card capacity
What is the maximum SD card capacity for the Pi Zero 2 W? Can it handle 1 TB for the operating system + data all in the SD card?
Here they say for the Rasbperry Pi Zero:

Because of a hardware limitation, the following devices will only boot from a boot partition of 256GB or less

which is not clear to me whether

It holds for the Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W as well, and
If the boot partition is smaller, can the OS be installed in a 1 TB partition and use all the remaining space for data?


The answer is in the document you referenced.
For the Pi Zero 2W you can use an SD card of up to 2 TB.
The Zero 2W is not a Pi Zero; none of the remarks/comments re the "Zero" apply to the "Zero 2W".
WRT partitioning: If you use the Raspberry Pi Imager, it will set up a minimal /boot partition, and the rest will go to / (the root partition).
And yes - if you want to re-partition either /boot or / you may do so using one of several tools; e.g. parted, fdisk or the GUI Gparted (see this REF for details).  You also need to resize the filesystems in the partitions, which is a separate process; see man resizefs.  If you are using raspios, raspi-config should have an option which will do all this for you.

Beware that "re-partitioning" is independent of re-sizing the filesystems inside the partitions, and that if you do one without the other (when growing, resize the partition first, when shrinking, resize the fs first) you will either end up with something that isn't resized WRT the fs or something where the fs has been partially destroyed (which may easily == fully catastrophic).   I think gparted might take care of that for you but fdisk and parted definitely do not.

@goldilocks: Excellent point. I wish you'd edit this answer to explain how that's done.

@goldilocks: Beautiful edit... I wish I could vote for it. lol

I can empirically confirm that up to 1 TB everything works fine. I did this: 1. Used the Raspberry Pi Imager on a 1 TB SD card. 2. Put it into my RPi Zero 2 W and booted for the first time, everything worked fine. 3. Moved the SD card back to my Ubuntu PC and used "Disks" app to shrink the root partition to 8 GB and created a data partition with all the rest. 4. Now everything is working fine in my Zero 2 W.

@user171780: Thank you for the feedback!
